# What is the purpose of data stored in JWT token payload?

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am new to JWTs and backend development in general, so I would like to get an answer to my question.

Currently I am working on my small project where the authentication is requiered and I want to use JWTs, and I consider what should I store in the JWT token payload and how can I further use that data?

I have read in one article that

> A JWT token should be stateless, meaning that you should store everything you need in the payload and skip performing a DB query on every request.

So what if I store user id in payload for instance, and then I want to access some info about the user in database with every request, why can't I do that? How can I provide a certain user with an accurate information if I don't have to perform any DB queries? Please explain me if I got it wrong and sorry for my poor English!

Comment: "*why can't I do that*" You *can*, but in certain architectures and at certain scales this isn't really practical to have hundreds of thousands of clients pounding your core database(s) repeatedly for the same information.

Comment: "*How can I provide a certain user with an accurate information if I don't have to perform any DB queries?*" You'd have to perform at least one database query up front to generate the JWT itself that *contains* the pertinent information, and the information stored therein would be "*accurate*"/current as of the time the token was generated.

Comment: You can store everything you need in the payload, it means that the JWT payload should contain all relevant information about the user or session that the server needs to process subsequent requests. This includes user identification, roles, permissions, and any other data necessary for authentication and authorization. The payload of a JWT is encoded, it is not encrypted. Therefore, sensitive information should not be included in the payload unless it is encrypted separately. Main reason is trust in the content JWT relies on the integrity of the token itself, primarily through its signature.

Comment: @BenchVue does it mean that I only have to store all relevant information about user (such as id, roles etc.) just to be able not to perform db queries to get additional information of that user?

Comment: @comediann, Yes, that's correct. By including relevant information about the user in the JWT payload, you can avoid the need to perform database queries to retrieve additional information about the user on each request.